# CSV importing: server or browser?

Tags: performance, csv, architecture, saas

From a conceptual point of view, what solution would perform better for a CSV importing task into a database in a SaaS?

1. Parse the CSV file in the browser, make an AJAX call to server for every row.
2. Upload the CSV file and let the server parse and insert it into DB

I know it is a too open question, given that no technology or hardware is specified. Anyway, what's better for the web server's performance? Getting thousands of connections or having to upload and parse big files?

Comment: Almost certainly #2. Connection setup is expensive. So is the overhead of the HTTP headers. (With small rows, the headers could easily be 10x the size of the row data.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question depends a bit, but from my experience, sending the data to a server and uploading a CSV into the database has several benefits.  For one, there is less "overhead per row" on uploading a straight CSV to a web or app server, and you can take advantage of things like server HW and physical proximity to the DB server for speed.  There are also a lot of tooks that handle CSVs efficiently on the server side, depending on the tech stack you choose.  I think it would be advantageous to send it en masse and have the server process the data upon upload.

HTH,
CDC